Is it possible to mimic LOOP control structure in NiFi?
I have more than hundreds of tables coming from different databases or API. Dependencies exist among some of those data sources, so I have ordered them and design the whole flow as linear mode: I let NiFi process them one by one. The basic structure of flow is:
1.load meta of all data source from controller database(ordered) =>
2.split records into multiple flow files =>
3.process flow files one by one(ETL) =>
4.end 

here the problem is, more than hundreds of flow files are queued with a few attributes. I want to further decrease memo footprint and simplify the flow as possible. So I want to load data source and process them one bye one. I think of loop and expect such a flow structure:
1.load the meta of the N-th data source from database into one flow file =>
2.process the flow file(ETL) =>
3.if another data source waits for being processed, goto step 1 =>
4.end


in theory it's possible to make a "loop" connection from end of last processor to the initial processor. so, flow will act as a loop. but you can manage concurrent threads per processor, merge small files into larger chunks... i don't see how the loop will help you with goals: "decrease memo footprint and simplify the flow"

The motivation of simplifying the flow comes from two sources.    At first, my flow is now getting more and more complicated, I have grouped processors to get simplicity a bit back at different abstraction level. However, the processor's count is hard to decrease. I try to cut processors as possible. Remove SPLIT is a idea.    Secondly, my whole flow is running as a queue. Now the queue is managed by NiFi, while queuing flow files should consume memory, threads ( It's just my guess -_-) or other resources, why I don't let database manage the queue? it'

Secondly, my whole flow is running as a queue. Now the queue is managed by NiFi, while queuing flow files should consume memory, threads ( It's just my guess -_-) or other resources, why I don't let database manage the queue? it's more effect queue in table. I believe that the less flow files pass through NiFi, the more performant it runs, the more simplicity I have.

At last,  I ever encountered java heap overflow error, it triggered my care about memo consummation, despite the error was not caused by the queuing of flow file.

I am sorry for this misleading question. NiFi can construct loop easily using relationships.
